# (Swift) collectionView и cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, swift

Мне нужно поработать с элементами коллекции. Но проблема в том, что после того как я возвращаю свою ячейку, я могу взять с нее все данные, но не могу ничего изменить, вплоть до того, что метод

```
newCell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

не вызывается. Если я правильно понял Swift, то мы больше не обращаемся к памяти, а создаем новую якутку с которой можем работать, а старая так и остается. В этого ничего не работает.

> Как мне ограничивать работу с уже существующей ячейкой?

P.S. Код который использую ниже, ничего необычного...

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
  {
    let rootViewPoint: CGPoint = (textField.superview?.convertPoint(textField.center, toCoordinateSpace: newOrderTableView!))!

    if let tmpIndexPath = newOrderTableView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(rootViewPoint) {
      if (tmpIndexPath.row < allLabelName.count - 1) {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tmpIndexPath.row + 1, inSection: 0)
        let newCell = collectionView(newOrderTableView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! EPNewOrderCollectionViewCell
        print(newCell.textField.placeholder)
        newCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return true
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот для тех кто не знал...

Вместо метода

```
let newCell = collectionView(newOrderTableView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! EPNewOrderCollectionViewCell
```

Нужно использовать

```
let newCell = newOrderTableView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! EPNewOrderCollectionViewCell
```